# “This site can't be reached - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET” via Google Chrome (49.0.0263.75) on Windows XP. Works with Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, anti-virus, ipconfig

I cannot get into many sites on my laptop with Google Chrome on Windows XP. I am using Google Chrome (49.0.0263.75) and FirefoxESR (52.9.0) and I am getting this error in Chrome:

> “This site can't be reached - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET”

I can load the sites with Mozilla Firefox and I would like to load them with Google Chrome too.
I have tried the following but nothing happened.

After looking at various sources, I have done the following:

- Closed all antivirus programs.
- Ran `ipconfig /flushdns` from command prompt.
- Emptied the cache for Chrome and deleted browsing data.
- Tried using Google DNS.
- Turned off then turned back on my home's router.

Comment: What version of Chrome and of Firefox are you using? Note that in both cases, it _will_ be an out-of-date version of the browser; neither are providing support for Windows XP any more.

Comment: The *web site* rejects connections from an antiquated browser. Are you stuck running deprecated XP? Any machine that supports XP likely can run an *up-to-date* version of Linux, with *up-to-date* browsers, whether Chrome, Chromium, Firefox or other. Here are some 32-bit Linux distros (my choice would be Debian or Ubuntu 16.04, which can be updated to 18.04 LTS): https://www.makeuseof.com/linux-distros-with-32-bit-support/ , https://www.debugpoint.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/, https://itsfoss.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/

Comment: Dear Giacomo
Thank you very much for your reply.
I am using version 49.0.0263.75 of Google Chrome and FirefoxESR version 52.9.0
The reason that I am using Windows XP in one of my laptops is because a few applications run faster than on Windows 10.

My machine is an old Sony Vaio
It was working a few years ago. Please help me to make it work if you want. Thank you

Comment: There's no way to make it work. WinXP is out of support for many years and dangerous - for you and everybody else - when used online. Web browsers, the one piece of software you MUST keep up-to-date no longer supports obsolete OSes. And *because a few applications run faster than on Windows 10* must be the most ridiculous excuse for not using a supported OS. As alreasdy commented use LINUX, end of story. If you need 32-bit distros then Debian or AntiX or a few others but not Ubuntu.

Comment: Here is the honest truth. The browsers your attempting to use do not support most https websites, as they do not support TLS 1.2+, and anything less than TLS 1.1 is completely and totally obsolete and insecure. Most websites don’t even support anything less than TLS 1.2 for that reason. The browsers your attempting to use is essentially trying to use AOL’s browser in 2024 that how big of a difference there is between the current version and the version your attempting to use.

Answer (score 2):

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34706/how-can-i-block-site-visitors-using-legacy-browsers

Websites can and do block access by outdated browsers and OSes. While it is *possible* that this issue is due to a networking problem, it is more likely that websites are acting correctly in limiting THEIR exposure to the severe security risk that your computer represents, AND repairing network issues on very old software is also likely to be difficult and unreliable.

You have two solutions that keep the current hardware:

1. Run a modern OS such as Linux on the old hardware.
2. Update Windows as far as the hardware will let you. Yes, 10 will run slower, but it is still actively supported by Microsoft, for a little bit longer, and both drivers and the internet will be better supported on that modern OS.